# How to update just a part of the activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

Well, the title says everything, but there's a little problem, I can't use a fragment or a loader, because I'm developing for android 2.3, so, how can I update just a part of the activity?

Comment: When you say update, what exactly do you want to update? like a button in the activity or draw on the screen?

Comment: Yes, I have a tableRow, and inside it there's a number(textView) and a button. So when a press that button, the number will be increased

Answer (score 2):

You can still use a fragment even in 2.3 by using the android-support-v4 jar

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the views by ID. As an example to change a EditText you can:

```
EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
test.setText("New Text");
```

Just change the cast to the proper type, so for a button:

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
```

So for your code if you have a button with the xml element `android:onclick="increment"` you can have a function such as:

```
public void increment(View view) {
    TextView number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number);
    number.setText(Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(number.getText()) + 1));
}
```